# Rename each slide and export in image format all the slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using VBA in powerpoint :
VBA code for a PowerPoint macro that renames each slide with the text contained in the rectangle shape
on the slide and exports all slides in image format to a user-selected folder

here is what I tried. I manage to select the folder for the image export but then I have an error on the line :

```
strName = strPath & "\Slide" & i & "_" & sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".jpg"
```

---

```
Sub ExportSlidesAsImages()
    'Déclaration des variables
    Dim i As Integer ' Variable pour stocker l'index de la diapositive en cours de traitement.
    Dim sld As slide ' Variable pour stocker la diapositive en cours de traitement.
    Dim strPath As String ' Variable pour stocker le chemin d'accès au dossier sélectionné par l'utilisateur
    Dim strName As String ' Variable pour stocker le nom de fichier complet pour chaque diapositive exportée en tant qu'image
    
    'Sélection du dossier de destination
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Sélectionner un dossier pour sauvegarder les images"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    'Exportation de chaque diapositive en tant qu'image
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        i = i + 1
        strName = strPath & "\Slide" & i & "_" & sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".jpg"
        sld.Export strName, "jpg", 800, 600
    Next sld
    
    'Message de confirmation
    MsgBox "Les diapositives ont été exportées avec succès dans le dossier sélectionné."
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can it be that one of the slides has no title?

Comment: shape (unknown member) : Object  does not exist :  this line is highlighted  strName = strPath & "\Slide" & i & "_" & sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & ".jpg"

Comment: @FunThomas  On all the slides there is a text in Rectangle, it is this text I would like to recover to rename each slide and then export them in image format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sld.Shapes` you have access to all shapes of a slide. You access single shapes using the index: `sld.Shapes(1)` or via its name: `sld.Shapes("Subtitle 2")`. `sld.Shapes.Count` tells you how many shapes you have on that slide.

Every slide in Powerpoint *might* have a title, but it doesn't need to. If you create a new slide, usually you see a shape that says *"Click to add Title"* - this will be the title of the slide. However, it's possible to delete this title shape or leave it blank and the slide will have to title.

`sld.Shapes.Title` will give the the title shape. However, if a slide has no title at all, you will get a runtime error *"Object does not exist"*. You can check if the title exists with `sld.Shapes.HasTitle`.

So it is likely that you have a presentation where at least one slide has no title set. The following function will check if a title exist, if not, it will return the text of the first shape:

```
Function getSlideTitleText(sld As Slide) As String
    If sld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        getSlideTitleText = sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.HasTextFrame Then
             getSlideTitleText = sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
             Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    getSlideTitleText = "(No title)"
End Function
```

Now all you have to do is replace the line where you set the file name with

```
strName = strPath & "\Slide" & i & "_" & getSlideTitleText(sld) & ".jpg"
```

---

If you want to check titles manually to find out which slide(s) are missing the title: On the "Review" ribbon, click "Check Accessibility":

[image]

Read here for more [information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/title-a-slide-c5286802-495a-4b47-a8ae-212fb8a7dc74)

Comment: To check for slides that don't have titles, you can also choose View | Outline.  If a slide has a title, it will appear next to the little slide icon in Outline view. Otherwise?  Missing title